# In unreal, I can't modify the bUseControllerRotation[Pitch | Yaw | Roll] at the constructor

Tags: unreal-engine4

I set the bUseControllerRotation[Pitch | Yaw | Roll] to the 'true' at the constructor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxoqd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxoqd.png)

and I check the changed value at the Blue pointer that inherit the "MyPawn"
but values are not change to the true.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSrAp.png)

i start this test at the blank project
so that variables are not changed at any script except and blue print
but if I change the bUseControllerRotation[Pitch | Yaw | Roll] at the BeginPlay() or Tick(), then the change have been applied.

then can't i modify the bUseControllerRotation[Pitch | Yaw | Roll]  at the constructor?

Comment: It is better to enter the code as text, not as image.

Comment: Serialization happens after the constructor is called. You can click the yellow arrows next to your variables in your blueprint to return them to default.